# tBLASTn vs NCBI TSA

Tags: proteins, taxonomy, blastn, tblastn, tsa

Is there a way to blast my proteins against all the TSA (Transcriptome Shotgun Assembly Sequence Database) belonging to a specific taxonomy using command line?

Thanks,
Marco

Comment: This seems like an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). Please add more detail to your question post, including information about the problem that you are trying to solve by doing this. Have you considered other approaches to discover the taxonomy of proteins?

Answer (score 0):

Just go to Blast [here](https://blast.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/Blast.cgi?PROGRAM=blastn&PAGE_TYPE=BlastSearch&LINK_LOC=blasthome)

1. Click where is says Database go to Transcriptome Shotgun Assembly Sequence Database (TSA).
2. Click where is says "Limited by" click organism and thereon specify the group of interest.

Thats it.

Comment: The OP wants to do this "using command line" though. And I haven't managed to find a good way to do that, personally, which is why I came up with that [really complex workaround](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/a/21806/298) for a similar question.